# ruby: index of all elements in array lesser than given value

Tags: ruby, arrays

I have an array

```
a=[10,20,30,10,3,2,200]
```

I want to find indexes of the element having value less than , say 21. I can surely do this in loop, but i was wondering if there is better one liner approach of it. Like we have in R.

Comment: You have checkmarked my answer, which came as a big surprise.  I put it up just for fun.  I would be interested in hearing why you selected it, considering that in real life you would not likely use any of the solutions I listed for the problem at hand.

Comment: they were very insightful solutions, which can lead to some potential ideas/solutions in other scenarios. Also, they worked for me :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here are some more choices for those occasions when a straigtforward solution just won't do:

```
a = [10,20,30,10,3,2,200]

a.size.times.with_object([]) { |i,b| b << i if a[i] < 21 } # or a.each_index.with...

a.size.times.map { |i| a[i] < 21 ? i : nil }.compact # or a.each_index.with...

a.zip( Array(0...a.size) ).select { |e,_| e < 21 }.map(&:last)

a.reduce([[],0]) { |(b,i),e| [e < 21 ? b << i : b, i + 1] }.first

a.each_with_object([]) {|e,a| a << (e.to_i < 21 ? a.size : nil) }.compact

a.each_with_object([[],[]]) {|e,(g,b)|
  e < 21 ? g << (g.size + b.size) : b << nil }.first

(a.each_with_object([-1]) { |_,b| i = a[b.last+1..-1].index {
  |f| f < 21 }; b << b.last + 1 + i if i })[1..-1]

b = a.dup
a.each_with_object([]) { |e,c| i = b.index(e); c << i if e < 21; b[i] = nil }

b = (a + [nil])
a.each.with_object([]) { |_,c|
  c << (a.size - b.index(nil)) if b.first.to_i < 21; b.rotate! }

a.join(',').gsub(/(\d+)/) { |e| (e.to_i < 21) ? $`.count(',') : nil } \
           .gsub(',,',',').split(',').map(&:to_i)

# All => [0, 1, 3, 4, 5]
```

Answer (score 4):

Do as below using [`Array#each_index`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.0/Array.html#method-i-each_index):

```
a = [10,20,30,10,3,2,200]
a.each_index.select { |i| a[i] < 21 }
# => [0, 1, 3, 4, 5]
```

> I am using ruby 1.8.5

Then do

```
a = [10,20,30,10,3,2,200]
a.size.times.select { |i| a[i] < 21 }
# => [0, 1, 3, 4, 5]
```

Comment: I am using ruby 1.8.5 which doesnt have each_index

Comment: apparently, neither of the above two worked for me in ruby 1.8.5

Comment: @user1631306 what did not work for you, can you post your error, and moreover it would be difficult to find support for 1.8.5, the last version supported is 1.9.3

Comment: 1.8.5? Really? Where did you find this antique version?

Comment: a.size.times.select{|e| e< 21}
LocalJumpError: no block given
        from (irb):8:in `times'
        from (irb):8
        from :0 
I am getting same error for each of the provided solutions

Comment: @user1631306 show us the error... Please.. If this versions are also not working, sorry, I can't help you out.. One suggestion - upgrade your *Ruby*, to get its all taste..

Answer (score 1):

This should do the trick and is linear:

```
a.each_with_index.inject([]) {|indexes, pair| indexes << pair.last if pair.first < 21; indexes}
```

Answer (score 1):

Ruby usually do not need to find indexes, why are you trying to do it?

This should work fine in 1.8:

```
[10,20,30,10,3,2,200].each_with_index.select{|x,_|x<21}.map{|_,i|i}
```